# Clickhandler on a feature in OpenLayers

Tags: event-handling, click, openlayers

I am trying to have a click event on a pop-up in openlayers. Right now I'm doing it with a hardcoded onclick in the feature:

```
    var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Points",{
            eventListeners:{
                'featureselected':function(evt){
                    var feature = evt.feature;
                    var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored("popup",
                        OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(feature.geometry.toShortString()),
                        new OpenLayers.Size(275,71),
                        '<div id="pincontent" onclick="pindetails()"><h3>' + feature.attributes.title +'</h3><div style="display: none;" id="pindescription">'+  feature.attributes.content +'</div></div>',
                        null,
                        false
                    );
                    popup.imageSrc = 'img/popup.png';
                    popup.autoSize = false;
                    popup.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
                    var offset = {'size':new OpenLayers.Size(0,0),'offset':new OpenLayers.Pixel(-74,-10)};
                    popup.anchor = offset;
                    popup.panMapIfOutOfView = true;
                    popup.imageSize = new OpenLayers.Size(275,71);
                    popup.relativePosition = "br";
                    popup.calculateRelativePosition = function () {
                         return 'tr';
                    };
                    feature.popup = popup;
                    map.addPopup(popup);
     //adding event listener
                    map.events.register('mousedown', popup, function(evt){alert('help')}, false);
                },
                'featureunselected':function(evt){
                    var feature = evt.feature;
                    map.removePopup(feature.popup);
                    feature.popup.destroy();
                    feature.popup = null;
                }

            }
        });
```

But the main OpenLayers div is intercepting the click so I have to click twice.. I'm not sure if there's a way to disable this. I've looked at the openLayers documentation and I'm not sure how to use their API to add an event listener for a click on a feature.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should add `return false;` after your function call in onclick to stop event propagation (which is the default).
Also have a look at the register method:

```
this.map.events.register('click', this.map, function handleMapClick(e) { ... }
```

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.6/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Events-js.html#OpenLayers.Events.register

Comment: no dice on the `return false`, I did try adding `map.events.register('mousedown', popcontent, function(evt){alert('help')}, false);` to the function for the featureselect and a few other places and can't get it to fire. The documentation abt events is pretty sparse

Comment: This could have to do with the z-index

Comment: Fixed it with 'OpenLayers.Event.observe(popcontent, 'mousedown',function(evt){pindetails()}, false); '  thanks for the events.register tipoff

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `evt.stopPropagation();` does not work. But using `return true;` in the `singleclick` event handler can stop the `Event-Propagation` from penetrating down to cascaded layers.